# How redis encode long integer?

Tags: redis

I've read across some code in redis, but I did not find how it handle long integer values (e.g. SET mykey 123456789123456789) --- I mean long integer(e.g. 8 bytes) that cannot be stored directly at the ptr field(4 bytes in my machine) of robj struct.

PS: I read the code of tryObjectEncoding function in object.c, but only found encoding of REDIS_ENCODING_INT data type. And there's no long type in redis in fact. Does that mean integers longer than 4 bytes will be encoded as REDIS_ENCODING_STRING?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REDIS_ENCODING_INT` actually represents an 8 byte number. See the method `string2l` in util.c - it attempts to convert the string to a long long.

In other words, integers between 4 and 8 bytes are encoded using `REDIS_ENCODING_INT` and not the default string encoding.

Comment: But in the tryObjectEncoding function in object.c, I see "o->ptr = (void*) value;", how could a long converted to a void* pointer without worring of lost of precision?

Comment: Oh, I try print sizeof(long) and sizeof(void*), they are both 4 bytes in my machine. Is that a coincidence or some relationship?